# Git: rebase onto development branch from upstream

Tags: git

I have local `master` and `develop` branches. I do all my work on `develop` and then merge them into `master` for releases. There is a remote branch, `upstream/master` which has changes I want, but I want to rebase my changes in `develop` (which shares a common ancester) on top of its changes and put them back into `develop`. I've already done `git fetch upstream`.

The [Git book chapter on rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) says to do:

```
$ git checkout experiment
$ git rebase master
```

Which I (assume) in my case would mean:

```
$ git checkout upstream/master
$ git rebase develop
```

But then I'd be on the `upsteam/master` and in detached head state. However, if I did a merge of `upstream/master`, I'd do that from `develop`, and the changes would be on `develop`, e.g.

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge upstream/master
```

So this way to rebase seems backward to me. I'd like to rebase my changes in `develop` on the `develop` branch with the changes from `upstream/master` similar to how the merge would work. Am I supposed to do the rebase on `upstream/master`, fix any conflicts, and then add it, stash it and pop it onto `develop`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The rebase would actually be:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase upstream/master
```

(`git rebase` should read: "rebase my current branch, here `develop`, **on top of** target branch, here `upstream/master`")

And the end result wouldn't be a detached head, but the newly rewritten `develop` branch.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest (most obvious to everyone) method is to update your `master` branch first, then rebase onto the updated `master` which is now exactly the same as `origin/master`:

```
$ git fetch origin                    # Get updates from remote.
$ git checkout master                 # Now bring master into sync:
$ git merge --ff-only origin/master   # if this fails you have stuff
                                      # in your master that they don't
                                      # have in theirs, and you need
                                      # to decide what to do about it
```

At this point, if all went well, `master` and `origin/master` are the same (as you can see with graphical viewers like `gitk`, or with `git log --graph --oneline --decorate`), and it should be clear how `git rebase master` will work.

But you don't actually have to do that.  You can just `git rebase origin/master`, while being on `develop`.  (This will leave your `master` un-forward-ed—presumably at some point you will want it forward-ed—so it's not really saving you much.  But it *is* easier to do now.)

---

The long boring "why" part: `git rebase` takes, in its long form, three points, which the documentation describes as *`newbase`*, *`upstream`*, and *`branch`*:

```
git rebase ... [--onto <newbase>] [<upstream>] [<branch>]
```

If you specify exactly one argument, as in `git rebase master`, that names the *`upstream`* and both *`newbase`* and *`branch`* are computed.  The *`branch`* is the current branch (i.e., `HEAD`, which must not be detached).  If you omit `--onto`, the *`newbase`* is taken as the *`upstream`* argument.  So if you're on `develop` now, and you run `git rebase X`, the *`branch`* is `develop` and both *`newbase`* and *`upstream`* are `X`.

The rebase method is, in effect (there are various internal optimizations and the effect on the reflog is a bit different):

1. check out *`branch`*
2. save a reference (`ORIG_HEAD`) to the commit to which *`branch`* points
3. reset it (a la `git reset --hard`) to *`newbase`*
4. for every commit in `upstream..ORIG_HEAD`<sup>1</sup> (in oldest to newest order), `git cherry-pick` that commit to add it to the just-reset branch.

Thus, as in the documentation:

```
   Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "topic":

                 A---B---C  HEAD=topic
                /
           D---E---F---G    master
```

when you `git rebase master` you get:

```
                   A---B---C         ORIG_HEAD
                  /
                 /       A'--B'--C'  HEAD=topic
                /       /
           D---E---F---G             master
```

(all I did here was take the example in the man page and add the `ORIG_HEAD` label and the `HEAD=`, to show that the original commits are "still in there", and that `HEAD` is a reference to `topic`).

So, what happens if you have your `develop` and `master` and they have their `master` which has a few extra changes in it?  Let's draw that:

```
A -- B -- C                         master
          | \
          |   D                     origin/master
          |
          E -- F                    HEAD=develop
```

Now you `git rebase origin/master`:

```
A -- B -- C                         master
          | \
          |   D                     origin/master
          |     \
          |       E' -- F'          HEAD=develop
          |
          E -- F                    ORIG_HEAD
```

At some point, you eventually move your own `master` to point to commit `D` too (and you drop `ORIG_HEAD`) giving:

```
A -- B -- C -- D                    master, origin/master
                 \
                   E' - F'          HEAD=develop
```

which is the same thing with some of the labels moved around.

That's all that the branch labels are, they are just labels.  Each label points to one (single) commit.  The commits themselves point back to previous commits, which is what builds the commit tree (or "commit DAG", really).

---

<sup>1</sup>`Git's X..Y` syntax hides a lot of "deep magic".  It means "all commits reachable from label *`Y`* that are not reachable from label *`X`*.  Which is exactly the set of commits that need to be cherry-picked, as those are the commits that were on *`branch`*, and were not on *`upstream`*, before the "rebase" op.  It "looks like" a time-based sequence at first blush, and that generally works in people's heads, but it's based on the commit graph topology.  Sometimes this trips people up though: `A..B`, where `A` is not related to `B` at all (because of multiple commit trees in the repo), means "every revision reachable from `B`.

Comment: A more detailed explanation (than in my answer) of the rebase part: +1.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful, clear and detailed. Much appreciated.

Comment: Would it be advices to do vise-versa where rebaseing branch onto master branch? : `git checkout master && git pull --rebase origin dev && git push -f`

Comment: @alper: rebase means "copy some commits, then abandon the originals in favor of the new copies". If you are on `master` when you run `git rebase`, the commits you copy-and-then-abandon are those that were on your `master`. If those commits are also on someone else's `master`, they might consider this abandonment rather rude. So it really depends on a lot of factors. There's no one right answer for all situations.

Comment: If you're up for this (not everyone is), one method that can work well is to *delete* your own `master` branch entirely. That way you *can't* use it by mistake. You'll always have to use a different name. When you go to create a new branch, or rebase, or whatever, you will have to use the *name* `origin/master` to refer to "their" latest `master` commit (whoever they are): you run `git fetch origin` to update, after which `origin/master` is their latest.

Comment: By not even *having* a `master` locally, you solve the problem of having your local `master` being behind. That is, we use the Alexander-the-Great solution to untying the Gordian knot: we just cut the darned thing out entirely and never bother untying it in the first place. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The command you are looking for is:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase upstream/master
```

However, Git is smarter than that, you can configure upstream/master as the upstream tracking branch of develop:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to upstream/master develop
```

Now when you do `git rebase`, it would automatically use 'upstream/master'. But even better, these commands:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase upstream/master
```

Can be simplified by simply doing:

```
git pull --rebase
```