# How to fix the structure of the project on GitLab?

Tags: eclipse, gitlab, egit

I have a problem with my project in Eclipse IDE. 
For the first time, I worked on an old version and made several changes.

I tried to upload the project on GitLab for the first time I configured Git on Eclipse IDE and I tried to commit and push "but I could do that only after doing a 'Fetch' from the remote branch and commit the 'Merge' change in my local repository.

Because I got this error:

```
rejected non-fast-forward
```

I followed this link [Egit rejected non-fast-forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474186/egit-rejected-non-fast-forward) to fix it.

The fetch downloaded all the git project files in my project on Eclipse. Until now in my project, I have a subfolder like this: `myProject/myProject`.

I made several commits and push and it works normally. I figured out that a subdirectory in gitLab `docroot` is created with every push I make.

This is the local project structure:

[image: structre_eclipse_project_problem]

This is the project structure on GitLab:

[image: structre_project_gitlab]

I want to delete `docroot/WEB-INF/classes` from GitLab.

How to delete this commit from GitLab using git plugin in Eclipse and how to correct my local project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docroot/WEB-INF/classes` is a folder. Git does not track folders, only files:

1. To delete a folder, you have to delete all the files in it.
2. In the *Git Staging* view, commit the deletions.
3. Make sure your current local branch is configured as *When pulling: Rebase* (in the *Git Repositories* view right-click the branch and choose *Configure Branch...*)
4. *Git > Pull* to make sure your commit is the latest commit in the upstream branch. If there are conflicts, you have to resolve them in the *Git Staging* view
5. *Git > Push to Upstream*

For details see the [EGit User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) and be aware that old Stack Overflow answers refer to outdated version of EGit.

Comment: In my project I have a subfolder `myProject/myProject`. I want to work on the project that exists on gitLab. I was working on the top project not on the subfolder which exists on gitLab because I can deploy and execute only the top project in my Eclipse server. pls check the local project structure. how to fix that?

Comment: `docroot/WEB-INF/classes` has probably the attribute _derived_ and is therefore only visible in the _Navigator_ view. Resources that are not in your workspace are shown in the _Git Repositories_ view below the _Working Tree_ node. If there is a problem, tell which step doesn't work: change the structure, commit changes, pull from upstream or push to upstream.

Comment: pls see the local project structure and tell me what should I delete exactly. you said "you have to delete all the files in it." does it means all sub-repertoire too?

Comment: Yes. In Git you will only have files, e. g. you can not commit an empty folder. Folders only exist as paths to files in Git. Assuming you have the single file `path/to/file` and remove it and commit the deletion, the folders `path/to/` and `path/` will disappear in Git even if they were not deleted.

Comment: I deleted the wrong folder but now my local projet will not work because I delete that folder. I can not deploy or execute my project.

Comment: The folder is deleted from gitLab but I can not run or deploy my local projet. I do not know if you understood me or not, I can deploy and execute only the top project in my Eclipse server.

Comment: If _"I deleted the wrong folder"_ can be read as I deleted some files by mistake: in the _History_ view right-click the commit that has be done by mistake and choose _Revert Commit_. This creates a new commit that undoes all changes of the commit to revert. Don't forget to push the revert commit to the upstream repository.

Comment: I recreated the delete folder manually in my local project and since now I have to work on the project up run it and deploy it,
and then I must copy its contents in the **subproject** and make a commit and push to gitLab of subproject.