# Egit keep throwing "rejected -non-fast-forward"

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

Suddenly, I have started to get the non-fast-forward rejected in Egit.
I have tried to do [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20010233/9727918),
but it helped only once, after this, when I'm doing more changes in the local - although the remote didn't changed - I'm getting again the annoying **rejected-not-fast-forward**

[image]

Then I must again to merge the branch with the remote.
I think it's not should be acting like that.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Do you understand the general reason for *why* this message happens? In short, it's because your _local_ and _remote_ branches have "diverged" - they each have changes that the other one does not have. Once you understand what that means, you can try to debug why its happening in your case. Without any access to your local and remote history, it's hard for anyone else to do more than guess about your exact scenario.

Comment: More specifically, does this answer your question? [What does "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/what-does-git-push-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected-mean)

Comment: EGit is here the messenger you shoot.

Comment: @IMSoP thanks, I knew it, but after I pulled and merged once, I though it should be OK from now on

Comment: The message comes from the server: your commit is not based on the last commit (someone else pushed something in the meantime). And because the server is configured not to allow fast-forward (which can be changed), your push is rejected. So you have to do a _pull_ first.