# git branching advanced usage, rebase from upstream branch

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase, upstream-branch, upstream

Following up on [Git: rebase onto development branch from upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200561/), basically the same ask as:

> I have local `master` and `develop` branches. I do all my work on `develop` and then merge them into `master` for releases. There is a remote branch, `upstream/master` which has changes I want, but I want to rebase my changes in `develop` (which shares a common ancestor) on top of its changes and put them back into `develop`. I've already done `git fetch upstream`.

Here is the (a bit more complicated/advanced) situation I'm facing with, starting from scratch.

1. I forked an upstream, and made my own changes ***from** its development branches* (`dev/br-1`), in my own new branch (`dev/br-2`), and `git push` to my own repo.
2. Now, upstream has advanced, both in its `master` and `develop` branches.
3. The way upstream advanced its `develop` branch is via `rebase`, i.e., all its own changes are *put back* on **top** *after rebase*.
4. My local repo is gone with my old machine, and I need to pick-up/git-clone from my own repo to continue with my customization.
5. I want to rebase my changes in my `dev/br-2` branch (which shares a common ancestor) on top of all the upstream changes.
6. I've already done `git fetch upstream` and was able to rebase my `master` with upstream's.
7. It is how to rebase my current `dev/br-1` from upstream, then `dev/br-2` from `dev/br-1` branch that makes my head spinning nonstop.

Although it looks like a very specific case, but the principle of how to do git branching and rebasing still applies, and the answer would be very educational to the general public. Please help.

*UPDATE:* So I looked at @torek suggested `git rebase --onto` command, like [How to git rebase a branch with the onto command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914052/), and all their refed docs, and think my problem is still one or two levels up than what I've read (because there are two repos and 5 branches involved). Here is the summary:

Situation at point#1:

```
A---B---C---D  master (upstream)
    \
     E---F---G  dev/br-1 (upstream)
             \
              H---I---J dev/br-2 (myown)
```

Situation at point#2&3:

```
A---B---C---D  master (upstream)
            \
              E'---F'---G'  dev/br-1 (upstream)
```

And I don't even know where should I draw my `myown` branch. Here is my current situation (which may have already been messed up, as I see `HEAD` might be in a weird place):

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 7aec18c (upstream/dev/br-1) more updates
* b83c3f8 more updates
* 4cf241f update file-a
* 200959c update file-a from main
* dc45a94 (upstream/master, master) update file-a from main
| * ce2a804 (origin/dev/br-2) update file-a
| * 0006c5e (HEAD -> dev/br-1, origin/dev/br-1) more updates
| * cdee8bb more updates
| * 85afa56 update file-a
|/  
* 2f5eaaf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add file-a
```

The ultimate goal is to place myown

`H---I---J dev/br-2`

branch on top of the newly rebased `G'`, in my own repo, after catching up with upstream. I.e., in my own repo, in the end, it should look like this:

```
A---B---C---D  rebased master (upstream)
            \
             E'---F'---G'  rebased dev/br-1 (upstream)
                       \
                        H'---I'---J' rebased dev/br-2
```

How to do that?

More explain by command:

```bash
 cd /tmp
 mkdir upstream
 cd upstream
 # prepare its `master` and `dev/br-1` branches

 cd /tmp
 git clone upstream myfork
 # prepare my own changes based on the `dev/br-1` branch into `dev/br-2`

 cd /tmp/upstream
 # advance its `master` 
 . . .
 # and its`dev/br-1` branches
 git checkout dev/br-1
 git rebase -X theirs master dev/br-1
 . . .
```

Now upstream has advanced, both in its `master` and its `develop` branches (via `rebase`), and I need to pick-up from my own repo to *continue* with my customization.

```bash
 cd /tmp
 mv myfork myfork0
 git clone myfork0 myfork1
 cd myfork1
 git remote -v
 git remote add upstream /tmp/upstream
 git remote -v
 git fetch upstream
 git rebase upstream/master

 git checkout --track origin/dev/br-1

$ git remote -v
origin  /tmp/myfork0 (fetch)
origin  /tmp/myfork0 (push)
upstream        /tmp/upstream (fetch)
upstream        /tmp/upstream (push)

$ git branch -avv
* dev/br-1                  0006c5e [origin/dev/br-1] more updates
  master                    dc45a94 [origin/master: ahead 1] update file-a from main
  remotes/origin/HEAD       -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev/br-1   0006c5e more updates
  remotes/origin/dev/br-2   ce2a804 update file-a
  remotes/origin/master     2f5eaaf add file-a
  remotes/upstream/dev/br-1 7aec18c more updates
  remotes/upstream/master   dc45a94 update file-a from main

$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 7aec18c (upstream/dev/br-1) more updates
* b83c3f8 more updates
* 4cf241f update file-a
* 200959c update file-a from main
* dc45a94 (upstream/master, master) update file-a from main
| * ce2a804 (origin/dev/br-2) update file-a
| * 0006c5e (HEAD -> dev/br-1, origin/dev/br-1) more updates
| * cdee8bb more updates
| * 85afa56 update file-a
|/  
* 2f5eaaf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add file-a
```

***UPDATE2:***

With above status, when I tried `--rebase-merges` as suggested by @VonC, I'm getting:

```
$ git rebase --rebase-merges --onto master $(git merge-base dev/br-2 master) dev/br2
fatal: Not a valid object name dev/br-2
fatal: invalid upstream 'dev/br2'

$ git checkout --track origin/dev/br-2
Branch 'dev/br-2' set up to track remote branch 'dev/br-2' from 'origin' by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'dev/br-2'

$ git rebase --rebase-merges --onto master $(git merge-base dev/br-2 master) dev/br-2
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/dev/br-2.

$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 344418c (HEAD -> dev/br-2) update file-a
* 4de3dec more updates
* 81af2ac more updates
* 1e3f9fb update file-a
| * 7aec18c (upstream/dev/br-1) more updates
| * b83c3f8 more updates
| * 4cf241f update file-a
| * 200959c update file-a from main
|/  
* dc45a94 (upstream/master, master) update file-a from main
| * ce2a804 (origin/dev/br-2) update file-a
| * 0006c5e (origin/dev/br-1, dev/br-1) more updates
| * cdee8bb more updates
| * 85afa56 update file-a
|/  
* 2f5eaaf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add file-a
```

Here, how to rebase my current `dev/br-1` from upstream, then `dev/br-2` from `dev/br-1` branch please
(detailed preparation can be found at https://pastebin.com/Df8VbCp2, if necessary).

Comment: Draw a graph (or have `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` do it, or see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452) etc.). This graph shows the commits that you have now. Then draw a graph of the commits you'd *like* to have, i.e., the same set of commits *except that* some have been copied to "new and improved" commits that have different *parents*.

Comment: Once you have the two graphs drawn, `git rebase --onto` will do what you need, even if it takes several `git rebase --onto` commands. Note that I generally like to use single uppercase letters for the existing commits, and then add a "prime" tick (commit `C'` is a copy of commit `C` for instance, except `C'` comes after `E` instead of after `B`) for the copies.

Comment: @xpt Can you try a `git rebase --rebase-merges --onto master $(git merge-base dev/br-2 master) dev/br2` to see if br-1 is rebased alongside br2? More on [`--rebase-merges` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309).

Comment: Please adapt the branch names with your actual branch names. Try and make the `git merge-base dev/br-2 master` work first: the goal is to get the commit from master, from which br1 then br2 were created.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, I've tried your command but the end result/graph doesn't look right to me. Because there are so many branches involves, I'm afraid a tiny of my mistake might mess up the whole process. So, would you start from point#4,  _I need to pick-up/git-clone from my own repo to continue with my customization_, and break down each steps, first rebase  master, then br-1, then br-2 please (again, detailed preparation can be found at https://pastebin.com/Df8VbCp2)? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is my current situation (which may have already been messed up, as I see HEAD might be in a weird place):
>
> ```
> $ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
> * 7aec18c (upstream/dev/br-1) more updates
> * b83c3f8 more updates
> * 4cf241f update file-a
> * 200959c update file-a from main
> * dc45a94 (upstream/master, master) update file-a from main
> | * ce2a804 (origin/dev/br-2) update file-a
> | * 0006c5e (HEAD -> dev/br-1, origin/dev/br-1) more updates
> | * cdee8bb more updates
> | * 85afa56 update file-a
> |/  
> * 2f5eaaf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add file-a
> ```

OK, I might draw this horizontally as:

```
A   <-- origin/master
|\
| B--C--D   <-- dev/br-1 (HEAD), origin/dev/br-1
 \       \
  \       E   <-- origin/dev/br-2
   \
    F   <-- master, upstream/master
     \
      G--B'-C'-H--I   <-- upstream/dev/br1
```

`A` = `2f5eaaf  add file-a`; `B` = `85afa56  update file-a`; and so on.  I picked the later ones to be the "primes" based on subject lines, although that might be backwards: perhaps the one labeled `B` should be `B'` for instance.  It seems likely that despite the same subject line for commits `B` and `E`, they have different patch-IDs (do different things to `file-a`), and it's hard to say whether matching up the two "more updates" commits here (calling the second one on the bottom row `C'`) was right.

(Note that there's no `dev/br2` here.)

But let's go back to this:

> [We start with]
>
> ```
> A--B--C--D   <-- master (upstream)
>     \
>      E--F--G   <-- dev/br-1 (upstream)
>             \
>              H--I--J   <-- dev/br-2 (myown)
> ```

I reformatted this slightly into my own preferred style (two dashes between commits, or one if using a prime marker to indicate that it's a copy).

> The ultimate goal is to place myown
>
> ```
> H--I--J   <-- dev/br-2
> ```
>
> branch on top of the newly rebased G', in my own repo, after catching
> up with upstream. I.e., in my own repo, in the end, it should look
> like this:
>
> ```
> A--B--C--D   <-- rebased master (upstream)
>           \
>            E'-F'-G'   <-- rebased dev/br-1 (upstream)
>                   \
>                    H'-I'-J'   <-- rebased dev/br-2
> ```

The commits that must be copied are precisely `E-F-G-H-I-J` (in that order).

If you have all six commits in your own repository (plus of course the four `A-B-C-D` commits), then—ignoring the desired *labels* for a moment—all we need to do is convince Git to copy, as by cherry-picking, the six commits in question.

The two options for doing this are:

- `git cherry-pick`, which leaves both the originals and the copies for us to find easily; or
- `git rebase`, which does the copying, then moves one (1) branch name around for us.

Moving one branch name is insufficient.  It's not particularly *harmful* and we could allow Git to do it, but let's just do this directly with cherry-pick.  We'll start by checking out the commit onto which everything should land, creating a new branch name:

```
git switch -c copied <hash-of-D>
```

or:

```
git switch -c copied --no-track upstream/master
```

(assuming `upstream/master` names commit `D`).  Then:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-D>..<hash-of-J>
```

or:

```
git cherry-pick upstream/master..dev/br2
```

(again the two *names* used here are just ways of typing in the raw commit hash IDs without having to type in raw commit hash IDs).  The two-dot syntax here means *any commits reachable from the second specifier, excluding all commits reachable from the first specifier*, so this means *commits from `J` all the way back to the root, minus commits from `D` all the way back to the root* which means `E-F-G-H-I-J`.

The result of this copying would be:

```
           E'-F'-G'-H'-I'-J'  <-- copied (HEAD)
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master (upstream)
    \
     E--F--G   <-- dev/br-1 (upstream)
            \
             H--I--J   <-- dev/br-2 (myown)
```

Now that we have the *commits* we want, we merely need to place the particular labels.  Since one or more of these labels will point to commit `G'`, it helps to redraw the above with `H'-I'-J'` on a row of its own:

```
                   H'-I'-J'  <-- copied (HEAD)
                  /
           E'-F'-G'
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master (upstream)
    \
     E--F--G   <-- dev/br-1 (upstream)
            \
             H--I--J   <-- dev/br-2 (myown)
```

The labels we want moved are:

- `dev/br1`, maybe; it should point to `G'`;
- `upstream/dev/br1`—but this is *our copy* of `upstream`'s `dev/br1`, so *we* don't move it directly, we have the remote named `upstream` move *theirs* so that our Git updates our memory of their name;
- `origin/dev/br1`: this is just like `upstream/dev/br1`;
- `dev/br2`: this should point to `J'`; and
- `myown/dev/br2` or maybe `origin/dev/br2`, but once again this is our Git's *memory* of some other repository's branch name, so we have to convince that *other Git repository* to move *their* name.

To move our own `dev/br1`, we can simply use `git branch -f` now:

```
git branch -f dev/br1 copied~3
```

for instance.  Since the name `copied` selects commit `J'`, and the `~3` suffix means "move back three first-parents", that will select commit `G'`.  The `-f` means *force* and causes our Git to move our `dev/br1`.

To move `upstream`'s `dev/br1` and cause our `upstream/dev/br1` to move, we now need to `git push --force-with-lease` or similar to `upstream`, which also assumes that we have permission (on whatever system hosts `upstream`: Git itself doesn't "do" permissions, but sites like GitHub and others do, for obvious reasons).  The `--force-with-lease` tells our Git to verify that their `dev/br1` still points where we expect; if we're sure that this will be the case, we can use plain `--force`.  Either way the command is, or resembles:

```
git push --force-with-lease upstream dev/br1
git push --force-with-lease origin dev/br1
```

which uses the fact that we forced our `br1` to point to `G'`.

The same process applies to making the various names point to `H'`, except that now we can use the name `copied`:

```
git branch -f dev/br2 copied
git push --force-with-lease origin dev/br2
```

Once we have done all this, we can switch to `dev/br2` or whatever and delete the extra branch name `copied`.  It existed only so that we had a nice simple way to *find* commit `H'` after all the copying.

**The key here is to understand that the *names* are largely irrelevant.  All that actually matters are the *commits*, which are identified by their hash IDs.  The trick is that we *find* the commits *using* the names, so that makes the names relevant.**

#### Alternatives

If you like, you can still do this with two `git rebase` operations.  Since things are relatively simple, we don't need the fancy `--onto` for the *first* one (but we will need it for the second):

```
git switch dev/br-1
git rebase upstream/master
```

This takes our starting point, which looks like this—note that I'm assuming things about the remote-tracking names this time:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- upstream/master
    \
     E--F--G   <-- dev/br-1 (HEAD), upstream/dev/br-1
            \
             H--I--J   <-- dev/br-2, origin/dev/br-2
```

and copies `E-F-G` to new-and-improved `E'-F'-G'`, placing them after commit `D`, as named by `upstream/master`:

```
           E'-F'-G'  <-- dev/br-1 (HEAD)
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- upstream/master
    \
     E--F--G   <-- upstream/dev/br-1
            \
             H--I--J   <-- dev/br-2, origin/dev/br-2
```

Having made the three copies, `git rebase` yanked the *name* `dev/br-1` off commit `G` and made it point to commit `G'` instead.

Now we will separately copy `H-I-J`:

```
git switch dev/br-2
git rebase --onto dev/br-1 upstream/dev/br-1
```

Here we needed the `--onto` to tell Git:

- Don't copy commits from `upstream/dev/br-1` backwards, i.e., *don't* copy commits `G` and earlier, but that's not where we want to put the copies!
- Put the copies after commit `G'`, i.e., the newly updated `dev/br-1`.

The result of *this* is:

```
                   H'-I'-J'  <-- dev/br-2 (HEAD)
                  /
           E'-F'-G'  <-- dev/br-1
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- upstream/master
    \
     E--F--G   <-- upstream/dev/br-1
            \
             H--I--J   <-- origin/dev/br-2
```

As with the first `git rebase`, Git did the copying of the commits found from the current branch name (i.e., `J` and back), excluding the commits we said *not* to copy (i.e., `G` and back), placing the copies wherever they go—this time that's separate from the "what not to copy" part—and then, having made the copies, `git rebase` yanked the *name* `dev/br-2` to point to the final copied commit (`J'`).

With the (local) repository's names now pointing to the copies, it's once again just a matter of using `git push --force-with-lease` or `git push --force` to get the *other* Git software, working with the two *other* repositories, to update *their* branch names, so that our own Git's memories in our remote-tracking names get updated.

(If you can't literally force-push *to* `upstream` or `origin`, you can still send the updated *commits*, e.g., via pull requests, but someone else will have to convince the other repositories to actually move *their* branch names to take in the new commits.)

Comment: OMG, I thought it was impossible giving nobody was able to answer it for so long, now I cannot believe the massive amount of explanation you've put into this answer. THANKS A LOT torek! The two approaches are very educational, telling me that even without any fancy commands, it is still doable by just simple commands. Super! And thanks for the 2nd method too, which is indeed simpler, and that'll be what I'll be doing in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

***WARNING:***
This is an *extremely* long answer as it includes every step's command, output and status. It is a log of how I achieved my goal, which was:

========

1. I forked an upstream, and made my own changes ***from** its development branches* (`dev/br-1`), in my own new branch (`dev/br-2`), and `git push` to my own repo.

   Situation at point#1:

   ```
   A---B---C---D  master (upstream)
       \
        E---F---G  dev/br-1 (upstream)
                \
                 H---I---J dev/br-2 (myown)
   ```
2. Now, upstream has advanced, both in its `master` and `develop` branches.
3. The way upstream advanced its `develop` branch is via `rebase`, i.e., all its own changes are *put back* on **top** *after rebase*.

   Situation at point#2&3:

   ```
   A---B---C---D  master (upstream)
               \
                 E'---F'---G'  dev/br-1 (upstream)
   ```
4. My local repo is gone with my old machine, and I need to pick-up/git-clone from my own repo to continue with my customization.
5. I want to rebase my changes in my `dev/br-2` branch (which shares a common ancestor) on top of all the upstream changes.

I.e., the ultimate goal is to place myown

`H---I---J dev/br-2`

branch on top of the newly rebased `G'`, in my own repo, after catching up with upstream. I.e., in my own repo, in the end, it should look like this:

```
A---B---C---D  rebased master (upstream)
            \
             E'---F'---G'  rebased dev/br-1 (upstream)
                       \
                        H'---I'---J' rebased dev/br-2
```

========

**Solution:**

Do it with three git rebase operations.

Again, The details of the preparation steps can be found at pastebin.com/Df8VbCp2, included below to  make a full story:

```bash
$ cd /tmp

$ rm -rf upstream/ myfork/

$  mkdir upstream

$  cd upstream

# == prepare its `master` and `dev/br-1` branches

$  git init

seq 12 | tee file-a
git commit -am 'add file-a'

$  git checkout -b dev/br-1
Branch 'dev/br-1' set up to track local branch 'master' by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'dev/br-1'

sed -i 's/^1/7/' file-a

git commit -am 'update file-a'

seq 5 6 | tee -a file-a
git commit -am 'more updates'
seq 12 | tee file-b
git commit -am 'more updates'

 cd /tmp
 git clone upstream myfork
 # == prepare my own changes based on the `dev/br-1` branch into `dev/br-2`

$  git branch -avv
* master                  2f5eaaf [origin/master] add file-a
  remotes/origin/HEAD     -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev/br-1 0006c5e more updates
  remotes/origin/master   2f5eaaf add file-a

$  git checkout --track origin/dev/br-1
Branch 'dev/br-1' set up to track remote branch 'dev/br-1' from 'origin' by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'dev/br-1'

$ git checkout -b dev/br-2
Branch 'dev/br-2' set up to track local branch 'dev/br-1' by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'dev/br-2'

sed -i '/9/{ N; N; s/^.*$/3\n4/; }' file-a 

$ cat file-a
7
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
3
4
72
5
6

git commit -am 'update file-a in dev/br-2'

 cd /tmp/upstream
 # advance its `master` 

 sed -i 's/^5/55/' file-a
 git commit -am 'update file-a from main'

 # and its`dev/br-1` branches
 git checkout dev/br-1
 git rebase -X theirs master dev/br-1

$ cat file-a
7
2
3
4
55
6
7
8
9
70
71
72
5
6

# Now upstream has advanced, both in its master and its develop branches (via rebase)
```

Continuing from there -- Start from point#4, pick-up/git-clone from my own repo to continue with my customization, and then first rebase master, then br-1, then br-2, using

```bash
git rebase upstream/master

git switch dev/br-1
git rebase upstream/master

git switch dev/br-2
git rebase --onto dev/br-1 upstream/dev/br-1
```

Details:

```bash
# I need to pick-up from my own repo to continue with my customization.
 cd /tmp
 mv myfork myfork0
 git clone myfork0 myfork1
 cd myfork1
 git remote -v
 git remote add upstream /tmp/upstream
 git remote -v
 git fetch upstream

$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 7aec18c (upstream/dev/br-1) more updates
* b83c3f8 more updates
* 4cf241f update file-a
* 200959c update file-a from main
* dc45a94 (upstream/master) update file-a from main
| * ce2a804 (origin/dev/br-2) update file-a
| * 0006c5e (origin/dev/br-1) more updates
| * cdee8bb more updates
| * 85afa56 update file-a
|/  
* 2f5eaaf (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) add file-a

$ git rebase upstream/master
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.

$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 7aec18c (upstream/dev/br-1) more updates
* b83c3f8 more updates
* 4cf241f update file-a
* 200959c update file-a from main
* dc45a94 (HEAD -> master, upstream/master) update file-a from main
| * ce2a804 (origin/dev/br-2) update file-a
| * 0006c5e (origin/dev/br-1) more updates
| * cdee8bb more updates
| * 85afa56 update file-a
|/  
* 2f5eaaf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add file-a

$ git switch dev/br-1
fatal: 'dev/br-1' matched multiple (2) remote tracking branches
$ git checkout --track origin/dev/br-1
Branch 'dev/br-1' set up to track remote branch 'dev/br-1' from 'origin' by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'dev/br-1'

$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 7aec18c (upstream/dev/br-1) more updates
* b83c3f8 more updates
* 4cf241f update file-a
* 200959c update file-a from main
* dc45a94 (upstream/master, master) update file-a from main
| * ce2a804 (origin/dev/br-2) update file-a
| * 0006c5e (HEAD -> dev/br-1, origin/dev/br-1) more updates
| * cdee8bb more updates
| * 85afa56 update file-a
|/  
* 2f5eaaf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add file-a


$ git rebase upstream/master
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/dev/br-1.

$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 53d26a9 (HEAD -> dev/br-1) more updates
* 3ad83f2 more updates
* c18eab7 update file-a
| * 7aec18c (upstream/dev/br-1) more updates
| * b83c3f8 more updates
| * 4cf241f update file-a
| * 200959c update file-a from main
|/  
* dc45a94 (upstream/master, master) update file-a from main
| * ce2a804 (origin/dev/br-2) update file-a
| * 0006c5e (origin/dev/br-1) more updates
| * cdee8bb more updates
| * 85afa56 update file-a
|/  
* 2f5eaaf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add file-a



$ git switch dev/br-2
Branch 'dev/br-2' set up to track remote branch 'dev/br-2' from 'origin' by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'dev/br-2'

$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 53d26a9 (dev/br-1) more updates
* 3ad83f2 more updates
* c18eab7 update file-a
| * 7aec18c (upstream/dev/br-1) more updates
| * b83c3f8 more updates
| * 4cf241f update file-a
| * 200959c update file-a from main
|/  
* dc45a94 (upstream/master, master) update file-a from main
| * ce2a804 (HEAD -> dev/br-2, origin/dev/br-2) update file-a
| * 0006c5e (origin/dev/br-1) more updates
| * cdee8bb more updates
| * 85afa56 update file-a
|/  
* 2f5eaaf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add file-a

$ git rebase --onto dev/br-1 upstream/dev/br-1
Auto-merging file-a
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file-a
error: could not apply 85afa56... update file-a
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
. . .

# fix it, then
git add file-a

$ git rebase --continue
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/dev/br-2.

$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 76d524a (HEAD -> dev/br-2) update file-a
* 53d26a9 (dev/br-1) more updates
* 3ad83f2 more updates
* c18eab7 update file-a
| * 7aec18c (upstream/dev/br-1) more updates
| * b83c3f8 more updates
| * 4cf241f update file-a
| * 200959c update file-a from main
|/  
* dc45a94 (upstream/master, master) update file-a from main
| * ce2a804 (origin/dev/br-2) update file-a
| * 0006c5e (origin/dev/br-1) more updates
| * cdee8bb more updates
| * 85afa56 update file-a
|/  
* 2f5eaaf (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add file-a

$ cat file-a
7
2
3
4
55
6
7
8
3
4
72
5
6
```

Comment: For explanations, please refer to torek's answer above.